# Текст, логотип и гамбургер на фоновом изображении

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, вёрстка, масштабирование

Верстаю макет [Макет с фигмы](https://www.figma.com/file/2rdy1qjBTl7D6BAC8S4qlf/Webovio?node-id=0%3A2). Для этой страницы есть фоновый рисунок и дополнительные:

Фоновый

[image: Фоновый рисунок]

Дополнительные - логотип

[image: Логотип]

и гамбургер

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть html код страницы

```css
:root {
  --my-screenwidth: 1366px;
  --my-screenheight: 768px;
  --layout-screenwidth: 1441px;
  --layout-screenheight: 811px;
}

._container {
  --layout-containerwidth: 1111px;
  --layout-containerheight: 43px;
  max-width: calc((var(--layout-containerwidth)/var(--layout-screenwidth))*var(--my-screenwidth));
  margin: 0px auto;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:regular,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <title>Webovio</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <main class="page">
      <div class="page__main-block main-block">
        <div class="main-block__container _container">
          <div class="margin-block__header">
            <div class="main-block__nav">
              <!--
                        <img src="img/triangles/white-triangle.png" class="main-block__logo_white_triangle" alt="logoheader">
                        <img src="img/triangles/yellow-triangle.png" class="main-block__logo_yellow_triangle" alt="logoheader">
                        -->
              <!--<div class="main-block__header_image_1">-->
              <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/oB0ua.png" class="main-block__logo_name" alt="logoname">
              <!--</div>-->
              <!--<div class="main-block__header_image_2"></div>-->
              <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/hO056.png" class="main-block__logo_hamburger_icon" alt="menulogo">
              <!--</div>-->
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="main-block__body">
            <div class="main-block__smalltitle">A place where</div>
            <div class="main-block__title">A creative agency for redemptive brands</div>
            <!--
                        <div class="main-block__text">
                            Anteelo is a leading strategic design firm that builds powerful digital solutions for startups and enterprises.
                        </div>
                        -->
            <div class="main-block__items">
              <!--<a href="" class="main-block__link main-block__link_yellow">Get in touch link</a>-->
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="main-block__image _ibg">
          <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tju6g.png" alt="cover">
        </div>


      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

В сss приведены размеры шапки, содержащей логотип и гамбургер. Здесь приведено свойство `max-width: calc((var(--layout-containerwidth)/var(--layout-screenwidth))*var(--my-screenwidth));`, вычисляющее максимальную ширину шапки с учетом значений ширины моего экрана и экрана макета, а также значения ширины шапки на макете, взятых с фигмовского макета (шапка состоит из логотипа и гамбургера).

Подскажите как сверстать макет так, **чтобы на фоновом рисунке заняли свои места логотип и гамбургер в шапке, а так же чтобы текст (заголовки A place where и A creative agency for redemptive brands) стал слева по горизонтали и посередине по вертикали рисунка, а также чтобы была возможность пропорционального масштабирования фонового изображения как на [Средства пропорционального масштабирования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1430091/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F#1430094)**. Должно быть как на [Макет с фигмы](https://www.figma.com/file/2rdy1qjBTl7D6BAC8S4qlf/Webovio?node-id=0%3A2). Я пытался прописывать стили, но у меня не получалось поместить текст, логотип и гамбургер на фоновом рисунке.

P.S. Точные отступы не нужны. Подскажите как сверстать, чтобы на фоновом изображении оказалось содержимое страницы, включая текст, логотип и гамбургер.

Comment: Видел уже несколько вопросов от Вас, Вы рассматриваете очень странную тему. Никто не верстает наложением картинок уже очень давно (и таких кейсов, где действительно так необходимо делать, вообще почти нет). Более того, и раньше никто не делал так, логотип был бы в png без фона и вставлялся как надо. Сейчас же Вы должны выгрузить логотип в SVG, можно и иконку меню тоже (хотя и в CSS тоже можно сделать), а остальное уже чисто верстка на CSS.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar мне нужно получить нужный результат (**необязательно наложением картинок**) - мне **подойдет любой способ**. Помогите сверстать, так чтобы было **визуально** как в шапке на макете. Очень нужно, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: @VladimirGonchar как задать стили в css (желателен пример), чтобы получить нужный визуальный результат?