# Не работающее пропорциональное масштабирование и неправильное поведение шапки

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть фоновая картинка для сайта и дополнительные. Главная картинка

[image: Фоновая картинка]

Дополнительные - логотип

[image: Логотип]

и гамбургер

[image: Гамбургер]

Привожу html и css код

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxBpn.png');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
  /*position: relative;*/
  /* resize */
  overflow: hidden;
  resize: horizontal;
  /* resize */
}

.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.navigation {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 26px 0;
}

.logo {
  width: 258px;
  height: 40px;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
}

.logo:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.logo img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.burger {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.burger svg {
  transition: 0.2s ease;
}

.burger:hover {
  background: #f0f0f0;
}

.burger:hover svg {
  fill: #555;
}

.header::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: calc(810 / 1440 * 100%);
}


/*
.block img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
*/
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navigation">
      <a href="#" class="logo">
        <img src="https://svgur.com/i/jAx.svg" alt="Logo" />
      </a>
      <div class="burger">
        <svg width="18" height="13" viewBox="0 0 18 13">
          <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M0 0V1.8H18V0H0ZM0 5.4V7.2H18V5.4H0ZM0 12.6V10.8H18V12.6H0Z" />
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

1. Но в результате в полноэкранном виде шапка с логотипом и бургером не отображаются,
2. При масштабировании логотип и бургер оказываются внизу страницы
3. и само фоновое изображение не масштабируется

Помогите устранить эти 3 проблемы. Код для пропорционального масштабирования приведен на [Средства пропорционального масштабирования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1430091/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F) - пытался его использовать, но столкнулся с 3-мя вышеобозначенными проблемами. Объясните причины возникших проблем.

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxBpn.png');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 20px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.navigation {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 26px 0;
}

.logo {
  width: 258px;
  height: 40px;
  display: block;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
}

.logo:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.logo img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.burger {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  background: #fff;
  border-radius: 40px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s ease;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.burger svg {
  transition: 0.2s ease;
}

.burger:hover {
  background: #f0f0f0;
}

.burger:hover svg {
  fill: #555;
}

.header::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: calc(810 / 1440 * 100%);
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navigation">
      <a href="#" class="logo">
        <img src="https://svgur.com/i/jAx.svg" alt="Logo" />
      </a>
      <div class="burger">
        <svg width="18" height="13" viewBox="0 0 18 13">
          <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M0 0V1.8H18V0H0ZM0 5.4V7.2H18V5.4H0ZM0 12.6V10.8H18V12.6H0Z" />
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

---

> Объясните причины возникших проблем.

Вы не пытаетесь разобраться что почему случается, не изучили начальные знания по вёрстке и не работаете с "девтулом" браузера.

В прошлом [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1430094/221218) я показал вам как можно добавить блоку пропорциональное изменение размеров, при помощи псевдоэлемента с `padding-top` равным соотношению ширины и высоты какого-то элемента, в вашем случае фоновой картинки, чей размер `1440x810px`.

Т.к. суть этого способа заключается в том, что внутри блока ничего не должно растягивать его по высоте, только `::before {padding-top: ratio}`, то все элементы внутри него должны иметь `position: absolute;` относительно масштабируемого блока (родителя).

А ещё у родителя стоит `overflow: hidden`.

Если бы вы пользовались девтулом или же имели начальные знания, то решили бы первые две "проблемы".

---

По поводу третьей.

Опять же всё упирается в начальные знания, а именно в знаниях единиц измерения в CSS.

Вы установили блоку `height: 100vh`, знаете как ведёт себя `vh`? Оно выдаст блоку 100% высоты вьюпорта (окна браузера, фрейма и т.п.).

Ещё в прошлом ответе я установил блоку возможность изменять размер `resize: horizontal`, чтобы **продемонстрировать** решение с масштабированием.

Вы же впихнули его как готовое решение, что не правильно.

А ответ на решение проблемы такой:

`width: 100%` - это ровно такая же ширина как и у **родителя**.
`height: 100vh` - это ровно такая же высотка как у **вьюпорта**.
`cover` - будет растягивать картинку пропорционально так, чтобы не было пустот.

Из-за наличия у `header` `height: 100vh` ваша картинка заполнялась так, чтобы быть `100%` по высоте, а данная высота не будет изменяться при `resize`, так что ваша картинка визуально не масштабируется.
Но как только вы начнёте изменять высоту окна браузера, то увидите, что и картинка будет масштабироваться.

Comment: ваше фоновое изображение не масштабируется пропорционально при уменьшении ширины экрана.

Comment: Вы не правы, оно масштабируется. Изображение размером `1440x810`, когда размер вьюпорта 1000 по ширине, изображение будет размером `1000x562.5` и т.п. при любой ширине вьюпорта. Это и есть масштабирование.

Comment: нажмите на кнопку уменьшения окна в правом верхнем углу и заметите, что часть фонового изображения оказывается скрытым за пределами окна. В классе header нет свойств `overflow` и `resize`.

Comment: @wfamilyweb, я вам расписал, надеюсь хоть сейчас почитаете и подумаете. И мой совет, закройте видео на ютубе и начните читать [отсюда](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web) прямо сейчас.

Comment: вы только не серчайте, но фоновое изображение стало пропорционально масштабироваться при уменьшении ширины окна только после добавления в класс `.header` свойств `overflow` и `resize`. Без них не масштабировалось. Проясните эту особенность (вы только не сердитесь - просто я возможно не знаю css на должном уровне).

Comment: @wfamilyweb, Всё описано в ответе, я не знаю как вам ещё проще разжевать. Блок растягивается засчёт псевдоэлемента, который задаёт родителю высоту, картинка растягивается засчёт свойства [`cover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)